# How do you copy all the images referenced in a document into a single directory?

Tags: macros, graphics, external-files, scripts

I am finalising a book and I need to submit all the images as separated files along with the manuscript.

Now, images are all saved in different places and referenced with a relative path from my chapter files. E.g. `../replication_package/data/user_behav/my_img` from my `chap01.tex` compiled from `main.tex`.

Is there a way to script a copy function that searches all the images referenced in the different `\input`ed filed and copy them into a single folder (ideally renaming them using the enumeration of the resulting LaTeX-typeset document?

Comment: `texdepend` will tell you which graphics get included. Perhaps this information allows you to copy these files wherever you want.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat actually I see that a few FIGS are missed (I think that it depends on the fact that they don't have an extension in the Latex document...)

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdepend?lang=en) this should not happen, but it is of course possible that there are subtle points. It is also hard for others to confirm this, but I also see that one cannot add an MWE here easily. Anyway, the above was just a suggestion. (It usually works for me, I am using this to collect all files for an arXiv submission.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete .eps and .pdf that are not used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534522/delete-eps-and-pdf-that-are-not-used)

Answer (score -1):

If you move the images elsewhere, you will have to edit the references to match. Loads of fun if you have lots of `figure1`...

I'd store away a working copy of everything (you use version control, don't you?), and locate the commands including images by a search command, stash the full lines away for reference. Identify file names of images, check for duplicates. De-duplicate by renaming, process the result and check it makes sense. Move all images to a single place, search and replace the places using them. Process and check.

Find out if "all images" includes stuff generated *in* the document, like Ti*k*Z pictures, or commands calling e.g. `gnuplot`. Those would require extra work. Any such external commands will probably require special treatment.