# Delete .eps and .pdf that are not used

Tags: floats, automation, eps, winedt

I have been working on a paper for a long time. The paper has many figures and I have collected different versions of each figure overtime. These figures are in .eps and .pdf formats. Now, I would like to go through my figures and delete the ones that I am not calling in my latex file. Among 600 figure files, how can I automatically select only the 30 figures that I am using?

Comment: Do you like delete others for good? It seems that the simplest way is manually find used files and store them in new folder.

Comment: @Zarko I need to send my latex folder to an editor and I do not want to include the unnecessary files. Deleting it manually means that I should keep searching for files and keep re-running the file to make sure that I have not deleted a needed one. Of course, it is doable, but I was curious if there is a better way!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to put `\listfiles` as the **very first** command in your tex file.  That will put a listing of all files used at the end of the log.  Put any figure that isn't listed into a separate direct so that TeX shouldn't be able to find it.

(Another possibility would be to put all of your figures into a separate directory and just move back the ones that TeX complains about not finding.)

Comment: It might go without saying, but I wouldn't actually *delete* anything until I was sure that it wasn't being used, if even then.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Yes, I am not deleting them in my own folder. I am deleting them in the latex folder that I am going to share with an editor. I just want to have less clutter.